# jquery validation errorPlacement trouble

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The example of errorPlacement in the validation plugin section of jquery.com gives this example:

error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );

Which adds the error to the "td" after the input.  I am trying to do a similar thing but I am not using "td" elements.

This is what my HTML looks like:

`<p><label>Employee Number:</label><input type="text" name="eenum" id="eenum" class="required" /><span></span></p>`

I am trying to get the error to appear in the "span" after the input, but nothing I have been trying works correctly.  If the error appears at all, it is always preceding the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what did you try? It should be

```
error.appendTo(element.next("span"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this.  I've tried that and it still puts the error before the input.  If I try error.appendTo(element.after('aaa'));  It will put the 'aaa' where I want the error message to go, but that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: Are you maybe using floats or other measures to position the inputs? It works in a minimal environment: http://jsfiddle.net/e3UaC/

Comment: Thanks for the input, it seems that this may be more of a CSS problem.